Do exists an inverse Cayley–Dickson construction for deducing lower-dimensional number systems?
Is there a known inverse or reverse Cayley–Dickson construction that enables deduction of numbers in the reverse order, from higher-dimensional to lower-dimensional sets?
For example, starting from octonions and deducing quaternions, then complex numbers, and finally real numbers (possibly real numbers might be approximated as rational numbers represented by pairs of numbers)?
If such a construction does not exist, has there been any formal exploration or documentation of an inverse Cayley–Dickson construction in mathematical literature? What properties, insights, or theoretical discussions can be provided regarding this approach?

$
\newcommand\Cl{\mathrm{Cl}}
$I've moved my comments here because they are longer and there were various important typos. I don't consider this an answer.

Probably not what you're looking for, but any real Clifford algebra $\Cl_{p,q}$ has dimension $2^{p+q}$ and is $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-graded; under this grading there is an even subalgebra which is isomorphic to another Clifford algebra:
$$
\Cl^+_{p,q} ≅ \Cl_{p,q−1} ≅ \Cl_{q,p−1}.
$$
The complex numbers are $\Cl_{0,1}$ and their even subalgebra is $\\Cl_{0,0}≅\mathbb R$. The quaternions are the $\Cl_{0,2}$ with even subalgebra $\Cl_{0,1} \cong \mathbb C$. Clifford algebras are associative so octonions don't fit into this (though they are related to Clifford algebras).
$\Cl_{p,q}$ can be thought of as encoding all subspaces of $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ and all rigid transformations on them preserving the form
$$
  x_1^2+⋯+x_p^2−x_{p+1}^2-⋯-x_{p+q}^2.
$$
The longest meaningful chain I can think of is
$$
  \Cl_{4,1}→\Cl_{1,3}→\Cl_{3,0}→\Cl_{0,2}→\Cl_{0,1}.
$$
$\Cl_{4,1}$ encodes all generalized $0,1,2$-spheres in 3D space and conformal transformations on them; $\Cl_{1,3}$ is the space-time algebra, encoding special relativity; $\Cl_{3,0}$ is the algebra of 3D Euclidean space; and $\Cl_{0,2}$ and $\Cl_{0,1}$ are again the quaternions and complex numbers.
